# Apollo client's codegen adds unwanted "or null" in my types

Tags: graphql, apollo, typescript-typings, apollo-client

Apollo client's codegen adds `| null` in the generated types, and I don't understand why they are there and how to get rid of them.

I see no reason why the API would return an array of null, so I don't want to check in my code weather the oject is null or not everytime.

Offending generated types from apollo codegen:

```js
export interface MusicGenres_musicGenres {
  name: string;
}

export interface MusicGenres {
  musicGenres: (MusicGenres_musicGenres | null)[];
                                        ^^^^^^
                                         WHY ?
}
```

My Graphql Schema:

```
type Query {
  musicGenres: [MusicGenre]!
}

type MusicGenre {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

Query in my TypeScript code from which are generated the types:

```
gql`
  query MusicGenres {
    musicGenres { name }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your schema, you have the following field definition:

```
musicGenres: [MusicGenre]!
```

This means that while `musicGenres` will be a list and will itself never be null, any item in the list *could* be null. If you want to indicate that all items in the list are also non-nullable, your field definition should instead be:

```
musicGenres: [MusicGenre!]!
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770501/graphql-non-nullable-array-list/46771890#46771890) for an extended explanation.