# How to define a nullable list with non-nullable items in a GraphQL schema using HotChocolate?

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm using C# 10 but with nullable reference types disabled on .NET 6 and HotChocolate 12.12.0.

My `Query.cs` has an entry like this:

```cs
public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFoos() { ... }
```

The generated GraphQL schema looks like this: `foos: [Foo]` (nullable array with nullable `Foo`-items)

When I add the `[GraphQLNonNullType]` attribute to the `GetFoos()` method, the generated GraphQL schema looks like this: `foos: [Foo!]!` (non-nullable array with non-nullable `Foo`-items)

What I want my schema to look like is this: `foos: [Foo!]` (nullable array with non-nullable `Foo`-items)

From what I've found (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46771890/10069673)) this should be possible somehow.

Does HotChocolate provide any way to produce a nullable array with non-nullable items in the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using Hot Chocolate.

Using annotation-based approach:

```cs
[GraphQLType(typeof(ListType<NonNullType<ObjectType<Foo>>>))]
public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFoos() { ... }
```

Using code-first approach:

```cs
descriptor
    .Field("foos")
    .Type<ListType<NonNullType<ObjectType<Foo>>>>();
```

https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/non-null/#explicit-nullability

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to enable nullable reference types and then explicitly mark the list as nullable.

Enable nullable reference types in the `.csproj` file:

```xml
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

```cs
public async Task<List<Foo>?> GetFoos() { ... }
```

To not change this setting for the whole project (as this likely breaks stuff), the [nullable directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) can be used to enable this feature just in certain parts of your code:

```cs
#nullable enable
public async Task<List<Foo>?> GetFoos() { ... }
#nullable disable
```

Don't forget to disable it again, otherwise it will also affect any other code below.

While this solves my problem for now, I would still be interested if there is a solution without enabling nullable reference types.